# Can I prevent Java Web Start from modifying the system path?

Tags: path, java, java-web-start

I have noticed that when I start an application using **javaws.exe** *pathtojnlpfile.jnlp*, javaws appends the JRE's path to the end of the system's `%PATH%` environment variable.

Is there any way I can prevent javaws from modifying the path in this way? I am using JRE1.5.0_15 on Windows Vista. I have read that older versions of the JRE do not do this.